# onCompeletionListener() not called every time and shuffle and repeat not working well

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, repeat, shuffle, seekbar

```
public class SongPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
TextView songName, artistName, albumName, durationPlayed, totalDuration;
ImageView next, previous, songImage, shuffle, repeat;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
SeekBar seekBar;
FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
List<Song> songList = new ArrayList<>();
Handler handler = new Handler();
Thread playPauseThread, nextThread, previousThread;
private Uri uri;
private int position;
boolean shuffleBoolean, repeatBoolean;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_song_player);

    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    songList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("songsList");
    position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0);

    songImage = findViewById(R.id.album_cover);
    songName = findViewById(R.id.music_name);
    albumName = findViewById(R.id.album_name);
    artistName = findViewById(R.id.artist_name);
    seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
    durationPlayed = findViewById(R.id.played_duration);
    totalDuration = findViewById(R.id.music_duration);
    repeat = findViewById(R.id.repeat);
    shuffle = findViewById(R.id.shuffle);
    floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.play_pause);
    next = findViewById(R.id.next);
    previous = findViewById(R.id.previous);
    playMusic();

    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null && fromUser) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress * 1000);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
    SongPlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
                durationPlayed.setText(durationConversion(currentPosition));
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 200);
        }
    });

    if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("playerShuffle", false)) {
        shuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_shuffle_24);
        shuffleBoolean = true;
    }
    else {
        shuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_shuffle_off_24);
        shuffleBoolean = false;
    }
    if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("playerRepeat", false)) {
        repeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_repeat_24);
        repeatBoolean = true;
    }
    else {
        repeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_repeat_24_off);
        repeatBoolean = false;
    }

    shuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("playerShuffle", false)) {
                editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("playerShuffle", false);
                editor.commit();
                shuffleBoolean = false;
                shuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_shuffle_off_24);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.shuffle_off, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("playerShuffle", true);
                editor.commit();
                shuffleBoolean = true;
                shuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_shuffle_24);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.shuffle_on, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    repeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("playerRepeat", false)) {
                editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("playerRepeat", false);
                editor.commit();
                repeatBoolean = false;
                repeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_repeat_24_off);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.repeat_off, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("playerRepeat", true);
                editor.commit();
                repeatBoolean = true;
                repeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_repeat_24);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.repeat_on, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public String durationConversion(int songDuration) {
    long s = songDuration % 60;
    long m = (songDuration / 60) % 60;
    long h = (songDuration / (60 * 60)) % 24;
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s);
}

void playPauseButton() {
    playPauseThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                        floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_arrow_24);
                        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
                        SongPlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                                    int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                                    seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
                                }
                                handler.postDelayed(this, 200);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_24);
                        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
                        SongPlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                                    int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                                    seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
                                }
                                handler.postDelayed(this, 200);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(SongPlayerActivity.this);
        }
    };
    playPauseThread.start();
}

private void nextButton() {
    nextThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        if(shuffleBoolean && !repeatBoolean)
                            position = random(songList.size()-1);
                        else if (!shuffleBoolean && !repeatBoolean)
                            position++;
                        if (position == songList.size())
                            position = 0;
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(songList.get(position).path));
                        metaDataRetriever(Uri.parse(songList.get(position).path));
                        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
                        SongPlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                                    int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                                    seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
                                }
                                handler.postDelayed(this, 200);
                            }
                        });
                        floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_24);
                        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(SongPlayerActivity.this);
                    } else {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        if(shuffleBoolean && !repeatBoolean)
                            position = random(songList.size()-1);
                        else if (!shuffleBoolean && !repeatBoolean)
                            position++;
                        if (position == songList.size())
                            position = 0;
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(songList.get(position).path));
                        metaDataRetriever(Uri.parse(songList.get(position).path));
                        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
                        SongPlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                                    int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                                    seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
                                }
                                handler.postDelayed(this, 200);
                            }
                        });
                        floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_24);
                        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(SongPlayerActivity.this);
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    nextThread.start();
}

private void previousButton() {
    previousThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        if(shuffleBoolean && !repeatBoolean)
                            position = random(songList.size()-1);
                        else if (!shuffleBoolean && !repeatBoolean)
                            position--;
                        if (position < 0)
                            position = 0;
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(songList.get(position).path));
                        metaDataRetriever(Uri.parse(songList.get(position).path));
                        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
                        SongPlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                                    int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                                    seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
                                }
                                handler.postDelayed(this, 200);
                            }
                        });
                        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(SongPlayerActivity.this);
                        floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_24);
                    } else {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        if(shuffleBoolean && !repeatBoolean)
                            position = random(songList.size()-1);
                        else if (!shuffleBoolean && !repeatBoolean)
                            position--;
                        if (position < 0)
                            position = 0;
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(songList.get(position).path));
                        metaDataRetriever(Uri.parse(songList.get(position).path));
                        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
                        SongPlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                                    int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                                    seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
                                }
                                handler.postDelayed(this, 200);
                            }
                        });
                        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(SongPlayerActivity.this);
                        floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_24);
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    previousThread.start();
}

private int random(int i) {
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.nextInt(i+1);
}

public void metaDataRetriever(Uri uri) {
    MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(uri.getPath());
    byte[] bytes = mediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
    final LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
    Bitmap bitmap;
    if (bytes != null) {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        layoutAnimation(getApplicationContext(), songImage, bitmap);
        Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGenerated(@Nullable Palette palette) {
                Palette.Swatch swatch = Objects.requireNonNull(palette).getDominantSwatch();
                if (swatch != null) {
                    GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, new int[]{0xff000000, swatch.getRgb()});
                    linearLayout.setBackground(gradientDrawable);
                    songName.setTextColor(swatch.getTitleTextColor());
                    albumName.setTextColor(swatch.getTitleTextColor());
                    artistName.setTextColor(swatch.getTitleTextColor());
                    durationPlayed.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    totalDuration.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_24);
                    floatingActionButton.getBackground().setTint(Color.WHITE);
                    next.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_skip_next_white_24);
                    previous.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_skip_previous_white_24);
                    seekBar.getThumb().setTint(Color.WHITE);
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        layoutAnimation(getApplicationContext(), songImage, null);
        linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_brown);
        songName.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        albumName.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        artistName.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_24);
        next.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_skip_next_24);
        previous.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_skip_previous_24);
        seekBar.getThumb().setTint(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorYellow));
        durationPlayed.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorYellow));
        totalDuration.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorYellow));
    }
    songName.setText(songList.get(position).songName);
    albumName.setText(songList.get(position).albumName);
    artistName.setText(songList.get(position).artistName);
    totalDuration.setText(Song.durationConversion(songList.get(position).songDuration));
}

public void playMusic() {
    if (songList != null) {
        floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_24);
        uri = Uri.parse(songList.get(position).path);
    }
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
    mediaPlayer.start();

    metaDataRetriever(uri);
    seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
}

public void layoutAnimation(final Context context, final ImageView imageView, final Bitmap bitmap) {
    final Animation animationIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_in);
    Animation animationOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    if (bitmap != null)
        animationOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                Glide.with(context).load(bitmap).into(imageView);
                animationIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
                imageView.startAnimation(animationIn);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
    else
        animationOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.album_cover).into(imageView);
                animationIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
                imageView.startAnimation(animationIn);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
    imageView.startAnimation(animationOut);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    playPauseButton();
    nextButton();
    previousButton();
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    nextButton();
    position++;
    if(position >= songList.size())
        position = 0;
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(songList.get(position).path));
        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
        metaDataRetriever(Uri.parse(songList.get(position).path));
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }
}
}
```

I have two problems here:

1. is that when the current playing music finish onCompletionListener() called which is call nextButton()
   which checks if shuffleBoolean and repeatBoolean states are true or not, the problem here is that when shuffleBoolean and repeatBoolean are true the SongList keeps playing serially Regardless of shuffleBoolean and repeatBoolean states, but if i pressed next or previous buttons it checks for repeatBoolean and shuffleBoolean states and play next song correctly according to the states.
2. sometimes when i move seekBar to any position (seconds) in the bar, the songlist stops playing at the end of current playing song

my description maybe too long for the first problem but i meant to be clear and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to call next.performClick() in onCompltition() and remove all the other lines.
I don't know the reason that the firs way don't work but i thought of it as i need to call onClickListener() without clicking the button.